# What is the part-of-speech of the word "O" in the exclamatory sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech

The sentence I'm considering is this:

> The boy said, "O King, live for ever."

Is the word "O" in the above sentence an adjective?

Comment: What would you think of [migrating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) this question to [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com)? It's a tricky question, involving a little-known subtlety of English grammar, and your interest in how to tag the word for the Penn Treebank project suggests that you might get a better answer by asking linguists.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I think it should be tagged (i.e. treated by labeling it) as "interjection" or "exclamation" (UH in Penn Treebank). For example, [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/o_2) defines it as "interjection", [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/o#O-3) defines it as "exclamation", archaic: used before a name in the vocative, with an example *'give peace in our time, O Lord'*. IMHO, there are more important things in learning English as a second language than PoS, such as English verb forms, articles, etc.

Comment: It's a literary vocative particle.  (Note: **p**article, not article; it doesn't function anything like a determiner―or like an adjective, for that matter.)

Comment: @snailboat you say particle, the chosen answer says article; no clarity here. To me, it's an interjection. If people want to use a shorter word,   let them.

Comment: @pazzo If you want to call it an interjection, I won't argue.  That works out okay.  The important thing here is how it behaves, and it doesn't behave anything like an article or an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There happens to be a specific technical term for that word.   You're looking at the vocative article.

Authorities seem to disagree as to whether articles are adjectives.   I happen to agree with those that say they are.

Comment: Would oou be able to look at this list of part-of-speech tags and tell me which one would be the most appropriate here? https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

Comment: @Καrτhικ It's not listed! You'll need to ask the people who run the Penn Treebank project, but first look at [this](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/treebank/doc/tagguide.ps.gz). There is no one, true categorization of English parts of speech. People have invented many ways to categorize parts of speech, to suit many different purposes. Penn Treebank does not include "article" among its parts of speech, which is unusual; apparently they prefer "determiner". But I'm not sure if vocative "O" is a determiner—it's a somewhat arbitrary choice.

Comment: It is an arbitrary choice.  For the phrasing "O King", I'd have to class "O" as a determiner.  For the phrasing "O my dear King", I'd have to class it as a predeterminer.  Since both of those entries are on the list, I'd have to choose one of them in preference to "adjective".

Comment: How 'bout UH? I'm not  convinced that merely because "article" is the traditional name among students of Greek we can assume that its use in English is comparable to that of English articles or determiners.

Comment: Does this mean that there are four articles in English? Maybe even more? Too much of my formerly solid education has become a moving target.

Comment: As I count it, three.  There's the definite article (sole example "the"), the indefinite article (examples "a" and "an"), and the vocative article (examples including "O", "yo", "hey" and possibly others).  I don't speak Greek, but I feel that the "hey" of "Hey Mikey, eat this" does a different job than the UH "hey" of "Hey, that hurts!"

Comment: @AST Two.  *A* and *an* are allomorphs.

Comment: There is the zero-article in English, arbitrarily speaking. @ASTPace

Comment: I agree with the definition "vocative article". That seems to describe it precisely. However, I would say it is also an interjection.

Comment: @pazzo True, some linguists posit a zero article, and that would bring the count up to three.  But it's an unnecessary complication; see *The Myth of the Zero Article* (Berezowski 2009).

Answer (score 5):

Oh, dear.

It's originally not a word at all, but an "ejaculation" or "interjection"— a (presumedly) spontaneous sound expressive of strong emotion, such as surprise, vexation, joy or grief. It's also used frequently as  a "discourse marker" to perform a transition or cover a momentary groping for words.

In the early 12th century, however, English writers adopted the Latin and Old French use of *O* to signal that the following noun phrase is a "vocative"—that is, that the noun designates the person addressed. In the course of the evolution from Early Modern to Modern English it became conventional to spell the sound ‹Oh› when used as an interjection or discourse marker, reserving the bare ‹O› spelling for vocative uses, or to lend an archaic or exotic or "poetic" air.

It is not at all clear that vocative ‹O› has ever been anything but a literary form in English, except among people who conscientiously imitate literary use—there seems to have been a lot of this in the 19th century, and you occasionally hear it employed ironically by English professors. I'm quite certain I've never heard it used spontaneously.

So it doesn't really fit anywhere in the conventional parts of speech. If I had to assign it to a category I'd call it a literary [proclitic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic#Proclitic); but I'd rather not.

Comment: The Macquarie Dictionary defines both _hello_ and _O_ as interjections. You wouldn't say that _hello_ is not a word! Funnily enough, definition 2 of both words is _an exclamation of surprise, etc._!

Comment: You've never heard it used spontaneously? My boys use it all the time when they say, "O Father of mine, how may I honor and obey you?"

Comment: @Καrτhικ No doubt my son would, too, if that circumstance ever arose; but it hasn't yet.

Comment: I would say it's a word ; even um... is a word. I have to learn new ways of saying 'um...' when I learn a foreign language. People are, um, free to disagree.

Comment: @pazzo "Originally", I hedged.  Where you draw the line can be tricky, but at some point you have to distinguish non-linguistic sounds like screams, gasps and sneezes (and their stereotyped orthographic representations) from linguistic "words".

Answer (score 2):

Almost in all grammar books, the last or eighth part of speech is "interjection".  O is an interjection used in the entence presented to express a sudden strong emotion (invocation or wish).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an interjection. Just like the "O" in "O, what fun it is to ride!" or "Oh, I see."

Comment: Some people would spell it as _Oh, what fun it is to ride_ whereas others allow _oh_ to be spelt _O_. Neither rule is followed universally.

Comment: @CJDennis probably because it's mostly a spoken sound there is diversity in spelling, but this can be said of most words pre the printing press